# Fetching content from url's containing a SESSION ID

Tags: php, parsing, session, pdf, session-variables

I'm trying to get a few PDF files I need for a project from a website (legally), but am running into some issues.

The URL of the location of the PDF file is f.e. example.com/?download_id=290758&s=d12134cac7ddb2198d232bba75c07d57&t=2-1-2014%2016:19:00

So first of all I parse this URL from the page containing it with the following code:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com/Acer-CR-6530/manual-5-100076.html');

// find the download link containing the session ID    
foreach($html->find('a[rel=nofollow]') as $e) 
    $link = $e->href;
$link = $baseURL . $link; 
// Link: example.com/?download_id=290758&s=d12134cac7ddb2198d232bba75c07d57&t=2-1-2014%2016:19:00
echo file_get_contents($link);
```

This doesn't work. It doesn't output the PDF file. Should I use cURL? If so, I'm not a cURL pro so I would love to see code for doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the output then? Please provide one of `var_dump(file_get_contents($link));`

Comment: just because the session ID is in that url doesn't mean it'll actually get USED by the remote server. Perhaps they're expecting a session cookie which you're not sending.

Comment: @revo, the output is bool(false).

Marc B, sorry to ask, but I'm not very familiar with cURL, do you know of some readymade script which can do this?